# Run Espresso/Cucumber UI testing for modular project in Android

Tags: android, cucumber, android-espresso, android-module

I wrote a UI test scenario by Cucumber and Espresso for a modular Android project.
This project has a module that depends on the Base module.
When I run the test I got an error in the xml layout, because this module apparently doesn't have access to the Base module's resources (when test run only) for example, include a layout from the Base module or a custom view.

```
.Feature Enter receiver details > Scenario Outline "Register Person" FAILED
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 
in [package_name].test:layout/fragment_register_person: Binary XML file line #2
in [package_name].test:layout/toolbar_title:
Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout Caused by:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2
in [package_name].test:layout/toolbar_title:
Error inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
```

In this case I used :

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar_title" />
```

and a custom view :

```
<com.me.base.view.customview.RtlTextInputLayout
```

that are imported from the Base module.
and I also added :

```
androidTestImplementation project(path: ':Base')
```

in current module.

I ran my test by executing a Gradle command in Android Studio Terminal :

```
gradlew myModule:connectedCheck -Pcucumber -Pscenario="Register Person"
```

What can I do?